# Python - How to get Enum value by index

Tags: python, enums

I have an Enum of days_of_the week in Python:

```
class days_of_the_week(str, Enum):
  monday = 'monday'
  tuesday = 'tuesday'
  wednesday = 'wednesday'
  thursday = 'thursday'
  friday = 'friday'
  saturday = 'saturday'
  sunday = 'sunday'
```

I want to access the value using the index.

I've tried:

```
days_of_the_week.value[index]
```

```
days_of_the_week[index].value
```

```
days_of_the_week.values()[index]
```

and so on...
But everything I tried didn't returned me the value of enum
(eg. days_of_the_week[1] >>> 'tuesday')

Is there a way?

Comment: Do you need a class? Is it an assignment? Because you can easily get what you want using a dictionary.

Comment: @MSH It is not an assignment I am just discovering python

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is for C#, not Python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IIUC, you want to do:

```
from enum import Enum

class days_of_the_week(Enum):
    monday = 0
    tuesday = 1
    wednesday = 2
    thursday = 3
    friday = 4
    saturday = 5
    sunday = 6

>>> days_of_the_week(1).name
'tuesday'
```

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way is:

```
list(days_of_the_week)[index]
```

This will return the element from the Enum class. If you want to obtain its value:

```
list(days_of_the_week)[index].value
```

Comment: Is the ordering guaranteed by the Python language, or is it an implementation detail that potentially could change in the future?

Comment: It guaranteed by enum library. From https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html : "can be iterated over to return its canonical (i.e. non-alias) members in definition order".

Comment: The OP has a list with unique values. If the values are not unique, list(days_of_the_week) only creates a list with the unique values.

Answer (score 3):

Those are simply string constants.  They do not have an "index" and cannot be referred to that way.

However, you don't need to write that at all.  Python provides it.

```
>>> import calendar
>>> list(calendar.day_name)
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
>>> calendar.day_name[5]
'Saturday'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

For days of the weeks, python has inbuilt calendar module but if this is just an example, this is a way.

```
class days_of_the_week(str, Enum):
  monday = 'monday'
  tuesday = 'tuesday'
  wednesday = 'wednesday'
  thursday = 'thursday'
  friday = 'friday'
  saturday = 'saturday'
  sunday = 'sunday'

  @property
  def index(self):
    return list(days_of_the_week).index(self)
```